# How to tween/animate fog three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap, tween.js

So i am trying to change the fog density by tweening it is this possible because it doesn't seem to change here's my defaults:

```
var camera, densityFog, colorFog2;
                    colorFog2 = 0xfee2ed;
                    densityFog = 0.25;
                    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(colorFog2, densityFog);
```

and here is what I've tried using the libs GSAP and tweenjs:

```
tween = new TWEEN.Tween(scene.fog)
                .to({densityFog: 0.02}, 1000 )
                .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
                .onComplete(function() { }).start();
                    
                gsap.to(scene.fog, {
                        duration: 2,
                        densityFog: 0.02,
                        onUpdate: function () {
                            controls.update();
                            isZoomed = 0;
                            controls.enabled = false;
                            
                        },
                    });
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer uses `gsap`

Use an object eg. `myfog = { value: .5 }` and tween its `value` property to what you desire.

Then in `onUpdate`, set `scene.fog` to a `new THREE.FogExp2` with the current `myfog.value` as a parameter.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 5;
camera.position.y = 2;

// Init the object and fog here
var myfog = { value: .5 }
scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x00ff00, myfog.value);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 5);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);

scene.add(mesh);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x00ff00);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

animate();

// This animates the fog
gsap.to(myfog, {
  duration: 2,
  value: 0.002, // The end value
  onUpdate: function() {
    // New fog with current myfog value
    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x00ff00, myfog.value);
  },
  // These just infinitely repeat the animation
  yoyo: true,
  repeat: -1,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r127/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out how to use infinite loop